# When trying to connect with the server by the hostname, the onFailure method always executes?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to establish a connection between the device and the server using the host name. But, while running the application, the process never succeeded, and the onFailure method executes every time I open the Sign Up activity. I thought at first that the host name process threw a NullPointerException, but I made sure that it was working fine. Below, there is a code sample of the whole process. If anyone can give me advice,
Thank you...

Connection Process (with onSuccess and onFailure methods) in the overridden onResume method

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final LoginActivity parent = (LoginActivity) requireActivity();

        final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(parent);
        String hostName = sharedPref.getString(Utils.PREFS_HOST_NAME, MyApp.getDefaultHostName());
        boolean tls = sharedPref.getBoolean(Utils.PREFS_USE_TLS, MyApp.getDefaultTLS());

        final Node node = Cache.getNode();
        node.connect(hostName, tls, false).thenApply(new PromisedReply.SuccessListener<ServerMessage>() {
            @Override
            public PromisedReply<ServerMessage> onSuccess(ServerMessage result) {
                List<String> methods = UiUtils.getRequiredCredMethods(tinode, "auth");
                setupCredentials(parent, methods.toArray(new String[]{}));
                return null;
            }
        }).thenCatch(new PromisedReply.FailureListener<ServerMessage>() {
            @Override
            public <E extends Exception> PromisedReply<ServerMessage> onFailure(E err) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to connect", err);
                if (parent.isFinishing() || parent.isDestroyed()) {
                    return null;
                }
                parent.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    parent.findViewById(R.id.signUp).setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(parent, R.string.unable_to_use_service, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                });
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

Getting the default hostname process in the application class.

```
public static String getDefaultHostName() {
        return sContext.getResources().getString(isEmulator() ?
                R.string.emulator_host_name :
                R.string.default_host_name);
    }

//Initializing and getContext processes in the application class.
public MyApp() {
        sContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return sContext;
    }
```

isEmulator method to specify if it's running on an emulator or not.

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
        return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("sdk_gphone_x86")
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
                || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
                || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT)
                || Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("sdk")
                || Build.PRODUCT.startsWith("vbox");
    }
```

Thank you everyone...

Comment: `R.string.emulator_host_name :
                R.string.default_host_name` Sorry, we have no idea which host names you use. Or which setup you use.